# Do Futures always end up not returning anything?

Tags: scala

Given that we must avoid...

1) Modifying state
2) Blocking

...what is a correct end-to-end usage for a Future?

The general practice in using Futures seems to be transforming them into other Futures by using map, flatMap etc. but it's no good creating Futures forever.

Will there always be a call to onComplete somewhere, with methods writing the result of the Future to somewhere external to the application (e.g. web socket; the console; a message broker) or is there a non-blocking way of accessing the result?

All of the information on Futures in the Scaladocs - http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html seem to end up writing to the console. onComplete doesn't return anything, so presumably we have to end up doing some "fire-and-forget" IO.

e.g. a call to `println`

```
f onComplete {
  case Success(number) => println(number)
  case Failure(err) => println("An error has occured: " + err.getMessage)
}
```

But what about in more complex cases where we want to do more with the result of the Future?

As an example, in the Play framework Action.async can return a Future[Result] and the framework handles the rest. Will it eventually have to expect never to get a result from the Future?

We know the user needs to be returned a  `Result`, so how can a framework do this using only a Unit method?

Is there a non-blocking way to retrieve the value of a future and use it elsewhere within the application, or is a call to Await inevitable?

Comment: `result` (http://goo.gl/GeW9Pl) does not return `Unit`.
You have to see a `Future` as just a way to spawn computation on a different thread (I know I'm oversimplifying).

Comment: Isn't using Await blocking? Or is the idea that we will always have to block a thread somewhere.

Comment: Await is blocking. I'm just saying one way is to just wait for the computation to finish but meanwhile you can do other things or define computation on a un-finished Future.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to use callbacks such as `onComplete`, `onSuccess`, `onFailure` for side effecting operations, e.g. logging, monitoring, I/O.

If you need the continue with the result of of your `Future` computation as opposed to do a side-effecting operation, you should use `map` to get access to the result of your computation and compose over it.

Comment: Map will just produce another Future, so what would you do with that?

Is the idea that we eventually have to block and Await the result of the future? 

Or do we register a callback with a useful Unit method e.g. send a message (sounds realistic e.g. use Akka) or modify some state (doesn't sound like functional programming)?

Comment: @user2232887 Of course in the end you have to wait for the computation to complete and then do something side-effecting like outputting the result, otherwise what's the point in doing it? This isn't specific to Futures.

Comment: Generally, you don't want Awaits in your code (although they may be useful at times, it's rather an exception). The whole point of futures is to avoid blocking in your control flow, so once you start to use them, they tend to propagate through your codebase (because your functions will naturally return `Future[Result]`). End result of any program is I/O, and I/O is a side-effect by definition (it does not transform your data). Oftentimes, though we use libraries such as Spray in case of http for I/O so there is no explicit callback in your code, just a map that returns you an HTTP status.

Comment: Thanks @Tim I've done some more thinking driven by the idea that I/O has to happen i.e. the buck has to stop somewhere! Although println isn't returning anything, it's still manipulating some useful state somewhere (the console)!. If we replaced the call to println with writing to a socket somewhere. I can see how it's much more useful. Particularly with a web framework! 

I think I was too focused on state _within_ the application.

Am I along the right lines with this?

Comment: I think so. Technically, I/O still happens within your application, but it's so many layers of abstraction away it's easy to forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Future returns a unit, yes. That's because it's an asynchronous trigger. You need to register a callback in order to gather the result.

From your referenced scaladoc (with my comments):

```
// first assign the future with expected return type to a variable.
val f: Future[List[String]] = Future {
  session.getRecentPosts
}
// immediately register the callbacks
f onFailure {
  case t => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
}
f onSuccess {
  case posts => for (post <- posts) println(post) 
}
```

Or instead of println-ing you could do something with the result:

```
f onSuccess {
  case posts: List[String] => someFunction(posts)
}
```

Comment: I think I'm struggling most with realistic applications of someFunction. 

The API states this has to be a Unit method, but wouldn't these have to perform some sort of fire-and-forget operation (e.g. sending a message) or modify some external state?

Comment: someFunction does not have to return a Unit. Where did you see that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the return value of someFunction would be lost; because onSuccess can't return anything _**BUT**_ I think I've been too fixated on println being "useless". 

My new understanding: println is writing to the console. i.e. the application is doing something useful by writing some **data** somewhere. The "state" is just outside of our application.

I imagine, in the case of the Play framework there's probably an onComplete method somewhere that doesn't need to return anything, it just needs to write the result somewhere more "useful" e.g. a TCP socket. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Exactly. Anything that happens inside onComplete, onSuccess, onFailure can affect state. It just needs access to your console, TCP socket, execution context, or whatever it is you want to hand the result to. If you give more details about what you want to do with the result, you'll probably get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the kind of Future you are talking about are used for side-effects. The result returned by a Future depends its type :

```
val f = Future[Int] { 42 }
```

For example, I could send the result of Future[Int] to another Future :

```
val f2 = f.flatMap(integer => Future{ println(integer) }) // may print 42
```

As you know, a future is a process that happens concurrently. So you can get its result in the future (that is, using methods such as onComplete) OR by explicitly blocking the current thread until it gets a value :

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val integer = Await.result(Future { 42 }, timeout.duration)
```

Usually when you start dealing with asynchronous processes, you have to think in terms of reactions which may never occur. Using chained Futures is like declaring a possible chain of events which could be broken at any moment. Therefore, waiting for a Future's value is definitely not a good practice as you may never get it :

```
val integer = Await.result(Future { throw new RuntimeException() }, timeout.duration) // will throw an uncaught exception
```

Try to think more in terms of events, than in procedures.

Comment: I understand we can transform the Future into another future using map, flatMap etc.

But is it inevitable that we have to finish with a call to a Unit method?

What is the correct way to get the actual result of the future?

Comment: tell me if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f: Future[Int] = Future { 43 }

val result: Int = Await.result(f, 0 nanos)
```

So what is going on here?

You're defining a computation to be executed on a different `thread`.

So you `Future { 43 }` returns immediately.

Then you can wait for it and gather the result (via `Await.result`) or define computation on it without waiting for it to be completed (via `map` etc...)